# Trouble finishing a foil-shining animation over an image

Tags: html, css, css-animations

As a continuation of what I [started earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68778956/753531) I thought "what if I added a foil-shining reflection over the inner image?". So I did:

```css
wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 2.5%;
}

.border {
  /*background-image: linear-gradient(-225deg, #fff 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 40%, rgba(0, 255, 255, 0) 60%, cyan 100%), linear-gradient(45deg, #3023AE 0%, #f09 100%);*/
  background: #000;
  clip-path: url(#svgClip);
  height: 354.5px;
  width: 354.5px;
}

.outer {
  background: tomato;
  clip-path: url(#svgClip);
  height: 351px;
  left: 2px;
  position:relative;
  top: 2px;
  width: 351px;
}

.inner {
  height: 81.5%;
  left: 2.1rem;
  position:relative;
  top: 2.1rem;
  width: 82.5%;
  z-index: 1;
}

img {
border-radius: 1rem;
border: 2px solid #000;
height: 97.4%;
object-fit: cover;
object-position: 0;
width: 97.4%;
}

.foil{
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.foil:before{
  animation: shine 5s infinite;

  background: linear-gradient(transparent 0%,
rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 45%,
rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 50%,
rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 55%,
transparent 100%);

  /*transition: all 2s;*/
  content: "";
  height: 200%;
  left:-120%;
  position: absolute;
  top:-120%;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  width: 200%;
  z-index: 10;
}

@keyframes shine{
  80%, 100% {top:-120%;left:-120%;}
  0%, 20%, 40% {left:100%;top:100%;}
}
```

```html
<wrapper>
  <div class="border">
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="foil">
      <img src="https://media-exp1.licdn.com/dms/image/C4D1BAQFsdjpzrtQWUA/company-background_10000/0/1519796755846?e=2159024400&v=beta&t=tL2HSXGgliQAAqXK0ZvfDvXvdRD2j3Gpk_juoBRmYlM" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
</wrapper>

<svg width="0" height="0">
<clipPath id="svgClip" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
    <path d="M.067.067C.1676 0 .8379 0 .9385.067C1.0055.1676 1.0055.8379.9385.9385C.8379 1.0055.1676 1.0055.067.9385C0 .8379 0 .1676.067.067"></path>
</clipPath>
</svg>
```

But looks like I didn't get the animation steps right because the reflection starts, finishes and then there's a noticeable pause before it goes away returning the image to its full colours

Comment: Code updated from the original version to enhance the visibility of the "blinking" near the rounded corners

Answer (score 1):

Move it further away at 100%:

```css
wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 2.5%;
}

.outer {
  background-image: linear-gradient(-225deg, #fff 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 40%, rgba(0, 255, 255, 0) 60%, cyan 100%), linear-gradient(45deg, #3023AE 0%, #f09 100%);
  clip-path: url(#svgClip);
  display: block;
  height: 350px;
  object-fit: cover;
  position:relative;
  width: 350px;
}

.inner {
  height: 80%;
  left: 10%;
  position:relative;
  top: 10%;
  width: 80%;
  z-index: 1;
}

img {
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 1rem;
  left: 0;
    position: relative;
  top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.foil{
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.foil:before{
  animation: shine 5s infinite;

  background: linear-gradient(transparent 0%,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 45%,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 50%,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 55%,
    transparent 100%);

  /*transition: all 2s;*/
  content: "";
  height: 200%;
  left:-120%;
  position: absolute;
  top:-120%;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  width: 200%;
  z-index: 10;
}

@keyframes shine{
  100% {top:-150%;left:-150%;}
  80% {top:-120%;left:-120%;}
  0%, 20%, 40% {left:100%;top:100%;}
}
```

```html
<wrapper>
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="foil">
        <img src="https://media-exp1.licdn.com/dms/image/C4D1BAQFsdjpzrtQWUA/company-background_10000/0/1519796755846?e=2159024400&v=beta&t=tL2HSXGgliQAAqXK0ZvfDvXvdRD2j3Gpk_juoBRmYlM" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</wrapper>

<svg width="0" height="0">
    <clipPath id="svgClip" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
        <path d="M.067.067C.1676 0 .8379 0 .9385.067C1.0055.1676 1.0055.8379.9385.9385C.8379 1.0055.1676 1.0055.067.9385C0 .8379 0 .1676.067.067"></path>
    </clipPath>
</svg>
```

Comment: I don't see much difference. Except that now the blink near the curved border is even more accentuated (seems `:after` can't be curved, I don't know)

Comment: that's strange, it looks practically seamless in Edge 92
What about my first suggestion with opacity? https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/68785895/1

Comment: Had to create a pen to see the opacity suggestion 'cause this new version overwrote it but, it looks less blunt than move further away, but the blinking is still there. I've edited the code in the question to something slightly different so the blinking becomes more obvious